# Left Aligning a subview to UINavigationBar Large Title

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, uiedgeinsets, layoutmargins

I have a UIViewController as the root of a UINavigationController and I have set the preference for large titles as follows `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`

My goal is to align the left of my view to the left of the navigation title but I want to do it dynamically rather than by hard coding values. Here is the desired end result:

[image: UINavigationBar Alignment]

I try to retrieve the left or the x position of the navigation bar's title using

`let navigationLeftX = navigationController!.navigationBar.layoutMargins.left`

I also printed this value out and got the value `8.0`

So then I thought, I should set this as the x position of the the view created and it should line up, my code in `viewWillAppear`:

```
// Create a demo view
let demoView = UIView()
view.addSubview(demoView)
demoView.backgroundColor = .orange

// Get the current left margin of the nav title
let navigationLeftX = navigationController!.navigationBar.layoutMargins.left

// Add constraints to your view
demoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
demoView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: navigationLeftX).isActive = true
demoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
demoView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
demoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

The result is close but still quite off.

[image: UINavigationController UINavigationBar alignment with subview]

If I doubled the margin x value, it seems to align properly

```
// Get the current left margin of the nav title
let navigationLeftX = navigationController!.navigationBar.layoutMargins.left * 2
```

[image: UINavigationBar Alignment Swift]

So I was just about to conclude that apart from the left margin of 8 points, there was an additional 8 points padding and logically thought, If I set the left margin of the navigation to 0, I should see an 8 points padding so I did:

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.layoutMargins.left = 0
```

But to my surprise, it was actually at the left edge of the screen without any padding:

[image: UINavigationBar title padding margin alignment]

Can anyone explain this behavior and perhaps share the best way to dynamically align a view with the navigation bar title ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

[A similar question was asked another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70796546/setting-leading-margin-of-content-to-the-leading-of-navigation-bar-large-title-i/70811373#70811373)

I came across two ways which could potentially give this value:

**1. Iterating through the navigation bar hierarchy**

```
var leftMargin: CGFloat = 0.0

for view in navigationController!.navigationBar.subviews
{
    if let classToFind = NSClassFromString("_UINavigationBarLargeTitleView"),
       view.isKind(of: classToFind)
    {
        leftMargin = view.layoutMargins.left
    }
}

// Set your left margin of view to align to leftMargin variable
```

The two unknowns here is I am not sure if this is querying a private class and if this is fine. The second thing is, this class name could change in future iOS releases.

**2. systemMinimumLayoutMargins**

Another thing I came across was getting the [systemminimumlayoutmargins](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2865908-systemminimumlayoutmargins) which you could do like this:

```
var leftMargin = navigationController!.systemMinimumLayoutMargins.leading

// Set your left margin of view to align to leftMargin variable
```

This gives a value which works, however I am not sure if this was the intended usage to depict the left value of the title

I will not mark this as answered in case someone comes up with a better solution but just noted this for anyone this might help.